# How to get explanation why question is unclear?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question, vote-to-close

I have had a big problem over many months with a question. I try to tell the story as factually as possible. Help is appreciated. Here we go...

I asked a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/232086/) on Jan 27 at 14:29.

It was closed as unclear on Jan 29 at 23:20.

I edited for clarity on Jan 30 at 15:45, messaging all who closed it if it was now OK (in the comments). It was not reopened and message was not responded too.

I edited for further clarity again on Feb 8 at 15:49, messaging all who closed it asking of it was now OK. It was not reopened and message was not responded too.

As you can see on the link, somebody then deleted these comments, leaving only the comment to define symbols - which was done immediately in the first edit.

By Mar 19 at 12:30, I had given up hope those who closed question would let the reworded question open. I took drastic step to repost it [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/244358/).

It was marked as duplicate on Mar 21 at 7:11. This was of the course the case - a duplicate of the reworded closed question. In fact, I said this in the quesion "(Full disclosure: this is reworded version of closed question)".

I would like to know:

Q1) How can my question appear on the website without stigma of "closed" or "duplicate"?

Q2) Why do reviewers refuse to say why a question was closed?  Notably, it seems to me all symbols are defined and perfectly reasonable equations are given.

I try to be good person. All I wanted was reason reviewers kept question closed after I completed edits that they required. I believe the aim should be to increase quality of question until it can be reopened. I do not see how it can happen if moderators refuse to communicate. If you look at the question, I do not believe it is so unclear that no amount of future editing would ever render it comprehensible to anyone on this site. It does not seem plausible situation.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): Note that the specific post was handled by reviewers, not moderators.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7610/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks. If this meta question is closed as duplicate or unclear is there a meta-meta site? :-)

Comment: The question entered the reopen review queue due to your edit (which was good!), but the [reviewers decided](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/115870) to leave it closed, with a 3:1 vote. As to why they did so I can only speculate, but I think it is because your question is essentially just a request for a calculation, which many consider off-topic as homework-like. The latest discussion thread on that policy is [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7407/50583).

Comment: I voted to leave it closed because it looks to me you are asking us to do some calculations and not explaining physics concepts.

Comment: I do agree that *unclear*, at this point, is probably incorrect (as stated above, I'd go with the HW-like reason), but I don't think it's worth it to reopen it and close it just to change the close reason.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank you for answer. I am glad question is not thought unclear! It seems the reason question is closed is then because it is HW-like. I disagree with this because the two questions asked were "how to" - concept-like questions. In fact, I say in original post  "I attempted to show it by computing ...". My problem is conceptual -  how to proof something - because my method via computating commutator failed. I wish to know correct method to calculate it. Shall I edit question again to highlight it is concept and not HW-like question? Thanks for your help.

Comment: *How to do X* is **not** a concept question, it's a *procedural* query. A concept question would be, *I thought X was the case, but it seems Y is the case, why is that?* or *Why should Theory X depend on Y?* Do you see the difference between what you're asking and what a concept question is?

Comment: @KyleKanos Sorry for my English. I do not understand the difference. I said "How to find..." meaning "what is correct method to calculate". I call it concept because my understanding was to calculate via commutator, which did not give correct answer. Therefore I believe solution to my problem is conceptual.

Comment: A concept is an *abstract idea or a general notion*, to use a dictionary definition. The *procedure* by which to solve a problem is *not* either of those.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank you for definition and your patience. Although I still do not understand :-( Why do you think an understanding of what procedure should (or could) be used to solve a problem is not conceptual?

Comment: It's not a concept question because you aren't asking for an abstract idea, but the method by which to solve a (mathematical) problem.

Comment: @KyleKanos I am sorry, I am very confuzed now. Is it forbidden to ask what is the best way to tackle a problem? If a poster asks method to calculate ground state we cannot give answer: try variational approach?

Comment: Yes, asking for the method of solving a problem is against the current homework policy. I also would say that a large portion of these types of questions could be turned into a concept question (therefore on-topic) if the author took more effort in asking what they don't understand, rather than how to solve it.

Comment: @KyleKanos I nearly understand now. So this question (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150665/separation-of-variables-integration/150682#150682) should have been closed rather than answered?

Comment: Yes. Note that that was answered in Dec 2014, long before I took a harder stance on HW-like questions.

Comment: @KyleKanos Did your stance change in the last 3 months? (This question seems HW-like for example http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227349/ )

Comment: I don't think that one's a HW-like question, they're asking how pressure, volume & temperature are related to each other (yes it's rudimentary, but it's still a concept). Are you done rooting through my answers? Or do you plan to keep this going for a while? I have a job to do...

Comment: @KyleKanos Apologies. Thanks for explaining anyway and for your time.